# concat more rows in one with SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table result

```
team_id | match_id | result
----------------------------
1       |13        |  1-1
1       |13        |  2-0
1       |13        |  0-3
```

I want change it in this

```
team_id | match_id | result | result 2 | result 3
--------------------------------------------------
1       |13        |  1-1   |   2-0    |   0-3
```

Comment: Will it always be a fixed number of matches, or can the number of matches vary? Also, do you really need to do this at the data layer? It may well be easier to do at the presentation layer.

Comment: Also, is there nothing to order the result by? If not, the matches could show up in any order.

Comment: how do you determine wich result value has to be in result column1,2 or 3 ?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: the number of matches isn't fixed. I'd like do it in the data layer. The rows are already ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ordering is arbitrary and there are exactly thre, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select team_id, max(case when seqnum = 1 then result end) as result1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then result end) as result2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then result end) as result3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by team_id order by team_id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by team_id;
```

Comment: thx, this is what I want, but to do this I must fix the number of matches,  but it's ok ;)